# Debugging with sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, source-maps

I want to debug the javascript using sourcemaps, I am able to generate the sourcemaps correctly (via gulp build process using webpack). I am able to hit the breakpoints in the sourcemaps but as soon I want to watch any vaariable (in the watcher window) they are unavailable. Secondly I am not able to set breakpoint on every line?

Can you please suggest the solution for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a breakpoint at a lambda call in Google Chrome DevTools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664151/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-at-a-lambda-call-in-google-chrome-devtools)