# Backend API completes successfully but NG not receiving anything

Tags: angular

Front end Angular app sends a GET to a backend Node API server. While API successfully fulfills this GET, its response `res.status(200).send(data);` not triggers the breakpoint at NG caller, but Chrome F12 network tab shows there are data returned.

---- NG front-end component .ts:

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { mySvc } from '../mySvc.service';
import { record } from '../models/record';     

export class ListAllRecordsComponent implements OnInit {
    private allRecords: record[] = [];
    constructor(private mySvc: mySvc) {}
    ...
    public getAllRecords()
    {
      this.mySvc.getAllRecords().subscribe(response => this.allRecords = response, );
    }
}
```

---- NG mySvc.service.ts

```
import { record } from '../models/record';  
@Injectable()
export class mySvc {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/somewhere';
    getAllRecords(): Observable<record[]>
    {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .pipe(
                map((data: any) => data.record),        // ??? break point is not triggered as expected when API sends back 200.
                catchError( error => { return throwError('bad')}) 
            ) 
    }
```

---- Node API server controller:

```
exports.pgGetAll = (req, res) =>
{
    objPS.pgGetAll( (err, data) =>
    {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
        else
        {
            res.status(200).send(data);     // break point shows data has all records
        }
    });
}
```

---- objPS:

```
const pgGetAll = (cbFunc) => 
{
    pool.query('select * from "schema1"."table1"')
        .then
        (
            good =>
            {
                cbFunc(null, good)          // break point shows good has all records
            },
            bad =>
            {
                cbFunc(bad)
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the getAllRecords method from your service? Because you should subscribe to the observable somewhere...

Comment: @bits added to post, but if observable not getting anything, nothing to do with downstream.

Comment: What is the response on the browser's devtools `Network` section?

Comment: @noamsteiner good point, surprisingly data shows up there, thank you! Didn't think of it, just thought nothing returned. Curious why break point is not triggered.

Comment: It needs debug. You have any interceptors in the app? what did you try by now? If you get a response to the browser - remove the backend snippets from the question, it's confusing.

Comment: @noamsteiner no interceptors I add, but can you explain what interceptor you meant and give an example?

Comment: You can read about Interceptors on angular documentation. If you didn't add one yourself it's not relevant to discuss it here. From what you shared, everything seems ok. Can you describe how did you try to debug this by now?

Comment: @noamsteiner just setting breakpoint in order to go step by step and verify, that's how it was discovered breakpoint is not hit when API returns something. Fiddler was used to see if things returned, but it tells me something about encryption and security which I thought it's not relevant

Comment: @noamsteiner interceptor, this is a test project based on some on-line samples so maybe interceptor is added unintentionally. Can you name a few interceptor libraries?

Comment: just before map operator in `mySvc` put tap and try to console.log the data object. It might give you insight into what the structure of data object is.

Comment: @Setu console shows there are returns, further `tap( ev => console.log(ev.rows[0])),` shows the data of the first record. But, why it wouldn't trigger the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're getting back data. If you got trouble with your breakpoint only, try using a method for mapping the data and set your breakpoint there instead of setting it in your lambda:

```
map((data: any) => this.mapData(data))
```

Define this new method:

```
mapData(data: any) {
  return data.record; // set your breakpoint here
}
```

Few other things though: "data.record" sounds wrong to me, because what it should deliver is more than one records, not only one, so the singular name is at least interesting.

At least in the `mssql` package, a query would return an object in `data` called `recordset`.

Here a link to that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#query-command-callback

Comment: Breakpoint works inside of `mapData()`!  Why it didn't work in the lambda?

Comment: Look at this solution here, I hope this helps you, this seems to be a not yet supported debugger feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664151/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-at-a-lambda-call-in-google-chrome-devtools

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem has to do with the way in which Javascript lambda expressions are debugged.

Please, consider read the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664151/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-at-a-lambda-call-in-google-chrome-devtools) SO question, I think it will provide you with all the necessary information to successfully debug your code.

Comment: The accepted answer does provide a solution directly, I can only give a "useful uptick". Really appreciate the input, and will read the suggested answer. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome @Jeb50, thank you very much. Please, do not worry, I was aware of that. I usually try to provide a detailed answer but I came across the indicated question, and I think that definitively it provides a great guidance and a lot of solutions to your problem. I hope it helps. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix it (excerpt from your service):

```js
getAllRecords(): Observable<record[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<record[]>(url)
            .pipe(
                map((data: any) => data.record),      
                catchError( error => { return throwError('bad')}) 
            ) 
    }
```

I ran into this about a million times.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: can you share a sample?

Comment: Can you try removing the pipe and checking if it works?

Comment: Same removing whole pipe completely. `return this.http.get<record[]>(url);`

Comment: i know this is not good answer but try to remove all types from getAllRecords() in your service . if it works, at least you know the issue and what to fix

Comment: Good idea. First try verifying all your types and you may find any mistakes.