# Set breakpoint inside arrow, inline function in Google Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I cannot set breakpoint inside of arrow, inline function. It just sets  at the line 223. However, when I click this button, then debugger does not go inside this function. What I want is when I click at the button, then debugger should stop when `this.grid()` should be called.

[image]

My breakpoint always is hit inside of `this.grid()` function, not inside of `onExcel()` function. I would like that Google Chrome Dev Tools should stop inside of `onExcel()` function.

Comment: The source map doesn't include this info so you'll have to set the breakpoint inside the actual js file executed by the browser.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the reply. Is it possible to find actual js and where this code is executed?

Comment: Yes, it's also in the Sources panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've found this file. However, breakpoint cannot be set in `main.js` file. Maybe you can explain how it is possible to set breakpoint inside of actual js file?

Comment: Try reformatting it by pressing `{}` icon and/or disable source maps in devtools settings.

Comment: If this code is yours you can put the body of the function on a new line.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, it works! I reformatted to `{}` and it works! Thanks! Could you please make a reply and I will mark it as an answer! :)

Comment: @wOxxOm `Try reformatting it by pressing {} icon` I am sorry, could you show please where `{}` button is located? I am trying to find and see in Developer Tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a breakpoint at a lambda call in Google Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664151/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-at-a-lambda-call-in-google-chrome-devtools)